# Using jQuery to set up a flash player

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a flash player (used only for browsers not supporting html5 video) set up like this:

```
<object id="mpl" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="400" height="300">
    <param name="id" value="mpl" />
    <param name="movie" value="/r/player.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
</object>
```

For those situations where I need flash, this is how I'm trying to dynamically set the url.  It works in Chrome, but not IE8 (IE9 in IE8 mode) which is the one place I actually need this to work.

The error I'm getting is "Invalid argument" in jquery, on the line corresponding to the append method.

Does IE8 want me to do this a different way?

```
data.videoPlayerContainer.find("object").append($('<param name="flashvars" value="width=400&height=300&displayheight=300&file=' + encodeURIComponent(flashUrl) + ' &autostart=true&type=flv&bufferlength=10&javascriptid=mpl&enablejs=true" />'));
data.videoPlayerContainer.find("object").append($('<embed src="/r/player.swf" name="mpl" width="400" height="300" bgcolor="#ccc3ad" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" flashvars="width=400&height=300&displayheight=300&file=' + encodeURIComponent(flashUrl) + '&type=flv&bufferlength=10&showicons=false&shownavigation=false&autostart=true&javascriptid=mpl&enablejs=true" />'));
```

Comment: Have you tried using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) ?

Answer (score 2):

take a look at https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject this should help you finding a proper solution.

Comment: So you think the error is coming from this older flash object?  Which doesn't handle dynamically added content well?

Comment: possible, but swfobject should help you to fix crossbrowser problems.